# Fetch method post

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, fetch

I have an HTML code that when I submit it it falls into a fetch javascript that is in the post method, but it is updating the page and changing the url, it should not update the page and it is not inserting in the database.

html:

```
<form id='formcoment' onsubmit="fetchComent(e)">
    <h1>Deixar um comentario:</h1>
    <textarea rows="5" name="comentario" id="comentariopessoa" placeholder="Seu comentario aqui"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
</form>
```

js fetch func:

```
function fetchComent(e){
e.preventDefault();

var coment = document.getElementById('comentariopessoa').value;
alert(coment)
fetch('comentar.php', {method: 'Post', body: JSON.stringify({ comentario: coment})}).then(function(resp){
    if (resp.status == 200){
        res.text().then(function(t){
            document.getElementbyId('form').innerHTML = t;
        })
    }
})}
```

php:

```
<?php 
require_once('conecta.php');
require_once('banco.php');
session_start();

$main = new Main();

if (!empty($_POST['comentario']) && !empty($_SESSION['nomeuser']) && !empty($_SESSION['iduser'])){
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
    $nome = $_SESSION['nomeuser'];
    $faceid = intval($_SESSION['iduser']);

    $main->comentario = $comentario;
    $main->nome = $nome;
    $main->faceid = $faceid;

    $main->insereComentario($conexao);
    //header('location:./index.php');
    ?>
    <form id='formcoment' onsubmit="fetchComent()">
    <h1>Deixar um comentario:</h1>
    <textarea rows="5" name="comentario" id="comentariopessoa" 
    placeholder="Seu comentario aqui"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
    </form>
    <p>Comentario feito com sucesso!</p>
    <a href="index.php" onclick="logout()">Sair</a>
   <?php

    }else{

    ?>

    <form id='formcoment' onsubmit="fetchComent()">
    <h1>Deixar um comentario:</h1>
    <textarea rows="5" name="comentario" id="comentariopessoa" placeholder="Seu comentario aqui"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
</form>

    <p>Preencha todos os campos</p>

    <a href="index.php" onclick="logout()">Sair</a>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

the site updates and changes the url to: ....com.br/mae2/?comentario=x+x+x+x+x+&Enviar=Enviar

Comment: Try attaching the event handler via [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onsubmit`. I could be wrong but I don't think you get access to the event as `e` so your submit event probably isn't being cancelled.

Comment: You need to explicitly pass `event` not `e` into function call. Also can't nest form inside a form with the response. As mentioned, using `addEventListener` instead of inline `onsubmit` would be much better

Comment: @charlietfl an phill i made the changes but the same error continues, the page refreshes and the url gets strange

Comment: Check browser dev tools console for errors thrown

Comment: Please update your question to match your current code